# Importing a CSV file into Excel

Tags: optimization, vba, csv, excel

I need help making this code run faster.  I am using it to import a CSV file into Excel. It works, but it is very slow. The file is almost 20MB.

```
{Sub OpenTextFile()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim linitem As Variant
FilePath = "filepath.txt"
Open FilePath For Input As #1
row_number = 0
Do
Line Input #1, LineFromFile
LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, "|")

ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 30).Value = LineItems(0)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 29).Value = LineItems(1)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 28).Value = LineItems(2)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 27).Value = LineItems(3)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 26).Value = LineItems(4)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 25).Value = LineItems(5)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 24).Value = LineItems(6)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 23).Value = LineItems(7)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 22).Value = LineItems(8)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 21).Value = LineItems(9)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 20).Value = LineItems(10)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 19).Value = LineItems(11)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 18).Value = LineItems(12)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 17).Value = LineItems(13)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 16).Value = LineItems(14)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 15).Value = LineItems(15)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 14).Value = LineItems(16)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 13).Value = LineItems(17)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 12).Value = LineItems(18)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 11).Value = LineItems(19)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 10).Value = LineItems(20)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 9).Value = LineItems(21)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 8).Value = LineItems(22)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 7).Value = LineItems(23)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 6).Value = LineItems(24)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 5).Value = LineItems(25)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 4).Value = LineItems(26)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 3).Value = LineItems(27)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(28)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(29)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(30)

row_number = row_number + 1
Loop Until EOF(1)

Close #1
End Sub

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False` and then back to `True` once you're done with the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the "faster" thing but you can replace the 31 lines of assignments with a 3 line for loop:

```
For r As Integer = 0 To 30
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 30 - r).Value = LineItems(r)
Next
```

Programming is about automating repetitive tasks, this should also apply to the code you write.

Comment: True, i am a beginner. I tried a loop but i could not write one that works. Grateful for your help

Comment: I would hesitate to tag this as an answer. If your new here as well, you might want to wait awhile for answers to your actual question: How to make the code faster... vs this honestly good answer to an unasked question: How to make the code cleaner.

Comment: I have to agree with @WernerCD, I don't really think this solves your problem. Although to be fair codereview is not about solving programing problems, it's about reviewing existing code ;)

Comment: Point well taken.

Answer (score 7):

If I were to rewrite your code, I'd do it like this:

```
Option Explicit
```

Step one, always be explicit. Nobody likes seeing a variable being used that they never saw declared anywhere.

```
Public Sub ImportTextFile()
```

Step two, name the procedure after what it's doing, and make it do that.

```
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "filepath.txt"

    Dim fileNumber As Long
    fileNumber = FreeFile
```

`FreeFile` will give you a file number that's ok to use. Hard-coding a file number is never a good idea, even if you're only using one file.

```
    Dim inputData As String
    Dim lineCount As Long

    On Error Goto ErrHandler
    ToggleWaitMode True, "Importing text file..."
```

`On Error Goto ErrHandler` means if anything wrong happens (file not found, more data in the file than can fit on the worksheet, or whatever), we'll skip straight to an error-handling subroutine where we'll take good care of closing our file and toggle "wait mode" back off.

```
    Open filePath For Input As #fileNumber

        Do Until EOF(fileNumber)

            Line Input #fileNumber, inputData
            lineCount = lineCount + 1

            WriteLineContentToActiveSheet inputData, lineCount

        Loop

    Close #fileNumber
```

So the `ImportTextFile` procedure does nothing but reading the file's content. `WriteLineContentToActiveSheet` will do the worksheet-writing part.

```
ErrHandler:
    ToggleWaitMode

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Close 'closes any file left open
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If

End sub
```

The code under this *label* will execute even if no error occurred, this is why we're checking for `Err.Number` being other than 0. But regardless of whether there's an error or not, we always want to `ToggleWaitMode`.

```
Private Sub ToggleWaitMode(Optional ByVal wait As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal statusBarMessage As String = vbNullString)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'ensure status message gets displayed
    Application.StatusBar = statusBarMessage
    Application.Cursor = IIf(wait, xlWait, xlDefault)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not wait
    Application.EnableEvents = Not Wait

End Sub
```

This small procedure takes two optional parameters. If none are specified, "wait mode" is toggled off - this means the status bar message is reset, the mouse cursor goes back to default, Excel resumes redrawing the screen and fires events whenever something happens. "Wait mode" is just all that reversed :)

```
Private Sub WriteLineContentToActiveSheet(ByVal inputData As String, ByVal targetRow As Long)
    Dim lineFields() As String
    lineFields = Split(inputData, "|")

    Dim fieldCount As Integer
    fieldCount = UBound(lineFields)

    Dim currentField As Integer
    Dim targetColumn As Integer
    Dim fieldValue As String

    With ActiveSheet
        For currentField = 0 To fieldCount

            fieldValue = lineFields(currentField)
            targetColumn = fieldCount - currentField + 1

            .Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).Value = fieldValue

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

This small procedure takes a single line of data, splits it into as many fields as it has, and writes each field value into a cell of the active sheet. Using `UBound` we're no longer tied to a specific number of fields - if the file format changes, the procedure should still work. And if it doesn't, the procedure that called it will cleanly handle the error for us.

Local variables `currentField`, `targetColumn` and `fieldValue` are not necessary - they could all be inlined, but having them makes code easier to follow and allows you to place breakpoints to validate their values as you run the code line-by-line with <kbd>F8</kbd> when you're debugging.

---

Couple observations:

- You need to **indent** your code. Indentation makes it much easier to read, for yourself and anyone looking at it. Give that <kbd>Tab</kbd> button some lovin'!

  - Procedures define a *scope*, anything under it should be indented.
  - Within a scope, *code blocks* should also be indented - this includes `If` blocks, `With` blocks and any code that runs inside a loop.
- `OpenTextFile` is a bad name for a procedure that actually *imports* a text file.
- Be consistent with your naming: chose a convention, and stick to it.
- You're reading a file, that's an I/O operation and by [Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) this is going to fail one day or another. Make sure your code properly handles any error that could happen while processing the file, you don't want to leave a file handle opened by mistake.
- Importing a 20mb text file will take a while, even with screen updating turned off. Tell your user you're working, give'em a hourglass cursor, and you can even update the statusbar message every couple thousand lines read/written (just call `ToggleWaitMode True` with a new status message) so they know it's not frozen.

Comment: Thank you, i am here to learn. I will take the advice / critique and learn from it. Thank you for taking the time to look at my "code".

Comment: Thanks retailcoder, i appreciate your help. I learned a lot. I tried your code, and i am getting a "Array expected" @ Ubound(inputData). It just freeses

Comment: oops my bad, typo - should read `UBound(lineFields)`... fixed now.

Comment: UBound stands for "upper bound" and returns the upper boundary of an array. That's the number of fields we have in `LineFields` after the `Split`, and so it represents the number of fields we have - hence `fieldCount`.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it. it works but not faster. It gets stuck in imporitng the file. It is a large file so it might be that it will take time no matter what. Thanks a lot for your help, i appreciate it. God Bless

Comment: @user25830 As I said, `Importing a 20mb text file will take a while, even with screen updating turned off. Tell your user you're working, give'em a hourglass cursor, and you can even update the statusbar message every couple thousand lines read/written` - this is VBA, you can't have a *background thread* doing work in the background. So the best thing to do is update the statusbar every X lines read/written so the user knows your code isn't frozen.

Comment: See below answer from @DickKusleika, instead of `WriteLineContentToActiveSheet` you could have `ExtractLineContentToArrayIndex` and add an index to an array and then have `DumpArrayToActiveSheet` - I don't think it gets any faster :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `With` statement this way:

```
With ActiveCell
    For r As Integer = 0 To 30
        .Offset(row_number, 30 - r).Value = LineItems(r)
    Next
End With
```

Thus, Excel doesn't have to call the `ActiveCell` object at each loop.

Comment: It's still calling it - the `with` block is just sort-of hiding it, hence the readability debate around that keyword :)

Comment: @retailcoder: are you sure it calls it in each line, or does it call it once and maintain a reference to it?  Given that ActiveCell is a function, it should do the later, which should be a bit faster.

Comment: After [verification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266330(v=vs.60).aspx), it seems you're right about this. Sorry!

Comment: @Jmax: Assuming that VBA and VB.net do the same thing, that should be faster. See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288030/234954

Comment: Yup. +1 and I'm stealing this, I really thought `With` was merely syntactic sugar. Thanks @jmoreno for that link.

Comment: Thanks for all your insights and @jmoreno for the link. `With` can be tricky depending on which language you use (in javascript for instance, it should be avoided because it is very slow)

Answer (score 5):

One of the slowest parts of Excel VBA is writing to the grid. Whenever you have a lot of data to write you should put that data in an array and write it all at once.  Here's how I would rewrite your code to do that.

```
Sub OpenTextFile()

    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sInput As String
    Dim vaLines As Variant
    Dim vaLineItems As Variant
    Dim aNew() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long

    sFilePath = "filepath.txt"
    Open sFilePath For Input As #1

    'Read in whole file at one, then close it
    sInput = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1

    'Split the lines and the first line to set up aNew
    vaLines = Split(sInput, vbNewLine)
    vaLineItems = Split(vaLines(0), "|")
    ReDim aNew(LBound(vaLines) To UBound(vaLines), LBound(vaLineItems) To UBound(vaLineItems))

    'Loop through the lines
    For i = LBound(vaLines) To UBound(vaLines)
        vaLineItems = Split(vaLines(i), "|")

        'Loop through the items, add to aNew in reverse
        For j = LBound(vaLineItems) To UBound(vaLineItems)
            aNew(lCnt, UBound(vaLineItems) - j) = vaLineItems(j)
        Next j

        lCnt = lCnt + 1
    Next i

    'Write to the range all at once
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aNew, 1) + 1, UBound(aNew, 2) + 1).Value = aNew

End Sub
```

aNew is a poorly named variable that will hold the array that gets written to the sheet. By reading in the whole text file at once, you can redimension aNew to the right number of rows. Then by reading in the first line and splitting it, you get the number of columns for aNew (assuming they're all the same number of columns).

The loops simply fill aNew with the info in the order we want it. Finally, the array is assigned to the Value property.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to code the import of the file as a separate sheet. Then select used range and copy to where those values have to go.

This way you will let Excel do the hard part.